# How to delete a Workflow History list?

Tags: designer-workflow

I have a workflow history list that I keep accidentally using to create new workflows, but it is corrupt so I spend a lot of time recreating workflows because I can't figure out how to delete it, and it is the default.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workflow history list is a hidden list so it won't show up under `View all site content`,
you need to navigate directly to it by appending the following to your site's url  `/Lists/workflow%20history`.

You can use SharePoint Designer to delete the history list by going under `All Files -> Lists`.
The history list should be displayed there and you can go ahead and delete. But think really hard and long before you do so because of unintended consequences.

If you find that your site is worse off, you can recover the deleted list from the site recycle bin.

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks! I created a list with the wrong name by mistake, so I don't expect any unintended consequences from deleting it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this tool over here. Never actually tested but looks to be what you need!  [Cleanup Workflow History](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CleanWorkflowHistory)

Comment: This link no longer works